# unset part of a multidimensional variable with the elements of another array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to unset() some parts of my multimensional array?

I have an array similar like

```
$list['A_1']['AA_2']['AAA_3']['AAAA_4'] = 'stuff'; 
$list['B_1']['BB_2']['BBB_3'] = 'stuff'; 
$list['C_1']['CC_2']['CCC_3']['CCCC_4']['CCCCC_5']['CCCCCC_6']['CCCCCCC_7']['CCCCCCCC_8'] = 'stuff'; 
$list['D_1']['DD_2']['DDD_3']['DDDD_4']['DDDDD_5'] = 'stuff';
```

Normally I would do my desired unset()-ing with

```
unset( $list['A_1']['AA_2']['AAA_3'] );
unset( $list['B_1']['BB_2']['BBB_3'] );
unset( $list['C_1']['CC_2']['CCC_3']['CCCC_4']['CCCCC_5'] );
unset( $list['D_1']['DD_2']['DDD_3']['DDDD_4'] );
```

However I'd like to get the same result by unsetting them using the elements from another array:

```
$result = array('A_1','AA_2','AAA_3');
$result = array('B_1','BB_2','BBB_3');
$result = array('C_1','CC_2','CCC_3','CCCC_4','CCCCC_5');
$result = array('D_1','DD_2','DDD_3','DDDD_4');
```

I've tried to approach it with the simplest way I could imagine 
but sadly it's not as easy as that and doesn't work:

```
$result = array('A_1','AA_2','AAA_3');    
unset( $list[$result] );
```

returns:
**Warning:**  Illegal offset type in unset

Answer (score 1):

This should be worked

```
function unsetArray(&$list, $result) {
    eval("unset("."\$list['".implode("']['", $result)."']".");");
}
unsetArray($list, $result);
var_dump($list);
```

Comment: TBH I was hoping for something more sophisticated (read: non-eval) but it does do the job.  Thanks for that!  Small note for others though, don't forget to sanitize the elements of $list or Eval can become Evil in a snap of a finger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to form multidemensional array to unset. Here you are using single dimensional array. Just form array inside array in your result array.

Thanks.